# Change the color of object and link the choosen color to the next scene not all the color button

Tags: actionscript-3

Here is my coding using AS3:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;


var btts:Array = [red,yellow,blue];


var set_colors:Object = {'red':0xff0000,'yellow':0xffff00,'blue':0x0000ff};


var obj_color:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();


for(var i:int=0; i<btts.length; i++) {

  obj_color.color = set_colors[btts[i].name];
  btts[i].transform.colorTransform = obj_color;


  btts[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, changeColor);
}

function changeColor(evt:Event):void
{

  var b_name = evt.target.name;

  obj_color.color = set_colors[b_name];
  rec.transform.colorTransform = obj_color;

}



go.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToScene_6);

function fl_ClickToGoToScene_6(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(obj_color.color == set_colors[red])
    {
    gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 2");
    }   
}
stop();
```

Hopefully someone can help me to repair this code.This code shown that when i click all the color button it will go to Scene 2 but in my condition,I want only one choosen button will go to Scene 2.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you to deal with the background color and Stage.Resize, but you will need to adapt the code for the Color change...

package com
    {
        import flash.display.Graphics;
        import flash.display.MovieClip;
        import flash.display.Stage;
        import flash.display.StageAlign;
        import flash.display.StageQuality;
        import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
        import flash.events.Event;
        import flash.text.TextField;

```
    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        private static const ORANGE:int = 0xff9900;
        var bg:MovieClip;
        var bg_mask:MovieClip;
        var marginx:int = 10;
        var marginy:int = 10;
        var display:MovieClip;
        var displayTextField:TextField;
        var ellipseWidth:int = 90;
        var ellipseHeight:int = 90;
        public function Main()
        {
            super();
            bg = new MovieClip();
            bg_mask = new MovieClip();
            display = new MovieClip();
            displayTextField = new TextField();
            this.addChild(bg);
            this.addChild(bg_mask);
            this.addChild(display);
            this.display.addChild(displayTextField);
            displayTextField.text = "";
            displayTextField.x = ellipseWidth/Math.PI;
            displayTextField.y = ellipseHeight/Math.PI;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;  // or StageAlign.TOP
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            drawBackground();
            display.mask = bg_mask;
            addListeners();
        }
        private function drawBackground(thickness:int=1,lineColor:int=0x000000,lineAlpha:Number=0.5,fillColor:int=ORANGE,fillAlpha:Number=0.5):void{
            var g:Graphics = bg.graphics;
            g.clear();
            g.lineStyle(thickness,lineColor,lineAlpha);
            g.beginFill(fillColor,fillAlpha);
            g.drawRoundRect(marginx,marginy,this.stage.stageWidth-marginx*2,this.stage.stageHeight-marginy*2,ellipseWidth,ellipseHeight);
            g.endFill();
        }
        private function drawMask():void{
            var g:Graphics = bg_mask.graphics;
            g.clear();
            g.lineStyle(1,0x000000,0.3);
            g.beginFill(0xcccccc,0.1);
            g.drawRoundRect(marginx,marginy,this.stage.stageWidth-marginx*2,this.stage.stageHeight-marginy*2,90,90);
            g.endFill();
        }
        private function addListeners():void{
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ADDED,updateLabel);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE,updateLabel);
        }
        private function updateLabel(e:Event):void{
            updateDisplay();
            drawBackground();
            drawMask();
        }
        private function updateDisplay():void{
            var tf:TextField = displayTextField;
            tf.text = ("{" + this.stage.stageWidth + ";" + this.stage.stageHeight + "}");
        }
    }
}
```

Just add a function to change the Color, but this is a simple way to do this...

In the method drawBackground, just add the Color that You want...

Just edit the fillColor in drawBackground method...
This will be the same as on http://tatactic.be/stackOverflow/ChangeBG/StageResizeSimple.swf
But You can easiely change the Color too.

[EDIT]

here You may add a function thath will change Your BG color
So this should be a piece of cake... ;)

[/EDIT]

Best regards.
Nicolas.

Comment: @Uyu tell me why the answer was useless.
If it's the case, downvote te answer.
If that solved Your issue mark the answer as solved.
If the answer helps You to solve the problem, you may upvote the answer.
But please, give some feedback and if You downvote the answer let me know why!
Thank you and best regards.
Nicolas.

Comment: is the coding can be used for action script 3.0?

Comment: @Uyu Yes and compiled in Strict Mode!

Comment: I began with AS1 (prototype based), didn't even spend time to learn AS2 (pseudo / fake class based) then skip on AS3 immediately.

Comment: i cannot view the link that u give

Comment: i don't see the coding to link a button to specific scene in your example.

Comment: There's no link, I would only say that the code is pure AS3 :)